# useEffect not dispatching action in react/redux project

Tags: javascript, react-redux, react-hooks

I am working on a React/Redux project and am attempting to remove a progress spinner that is getting stuck on my error page. I have confirmed my `ClearAllSpinners` action is working correctly, but I believe it is clearing the spinners prematurely, prior to the spinner showing up, since it is not working.

In my error page component, I have the following `useEffect` hook, which I have been trying to dispatch my action from anytime the page renders or there is a change to isAnySpinnerActive:

```js
useEffect(() => {
  dispatch(ClearAllSpinners());
}, [dispatch, isAnySpinnerActive]);
```

I know the action clears the spinners as intended since the following function sets a spinner and then clears it after 5 seconds successfully (this function was used solely as a test):

```js
const addSpinner = () => {
  dispatch(ShowSpinner('test-spinner'));
  setTimeout(() => {
    dispatch(ClearAllSpinners());
  }, 5000);
};
```

Is there any other way I can dispatch my action anytime the error page is rendered and then again after any spinners may possibly appear, other than the `useEffect` hook I am using?

Answer (score 0):

you are using the `useEffect` hook which triggers to call after a variable or statement has changed or triggered by default as `componnetDidMount`. you can read more about that [here](https://reactjs.org/docs/hooks-effect.html).

these variables or states must be added as your dependencies array to `useEffect` work properly as your expectation.

you want to call your dispatch action in your `useEffect`, it's okay, but when?

your snippet tells that dispatch `ClearAllSpinners` when your component did mount!!

you can do this with your status variable(which controlling Spinner visibility) like this:

```
useEffect(() => {
    if(showSpinner) {
      // triggered when showSpinner is true
      setTimeout(() => {
         dispatch(ClearAllSpinners());
      }, 5000)
    } else {
      // triggered when your component did mount or when showSpinner was false!!
    }
}, [dispatch, showSpinner])
```